# Get request parameters inside socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I want to create a new document in a mongodb collection every time a socket is run, but these collections should belong to the page at which I am at.

Right now I am hardcording `pageId` like this

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  const pageId = '57cc491c95f2513e5aad2590';

  socket.on('new nodes', (positions) => {
    Document.create({pageId: pageId}, (err, doc) => {
      // ...
    });
  });
});
```

but I want to get the id from `req.params.pageId` inside an `express` route

```
app.route('/pages/:pageId').get((req, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The socket.io connection stands on its own and isn't part of an express route handler.  So, you can't directly access `req.params.pageId` from the socket.io connection because that request is over and done when the socket.io connection arrives.  So, you're going to have to include some additional information either when you connect from socket.io or when you send a particular socket.io message that indicates the page id.

So, you have a couple of choices:

1. When you connect from the page, you can include a query parameter on the connect URL that indicates the pageId.  Then, in your `io.on('connection', ...)` code, you can look at that query parameter to get the pageId.
2. When you send the `new nodes` message, you can include a data argument that specifies the pageId.

This can either be implemented in your Javascript on the page that figures out what pageId it is and inserts that as a the desired parameter or it can be done more automatically by whatever rendering engine creates your initial page (so the pageId is inserted at page render time directly into your code).

Comment: @Jamgreen - Does this help explain your options?